# find clickable xpath on a webpage

Tags: python, selenium

on below NSE site, I need to click the Download (.csv) button through selenium and I am using below code but its not working-

Site: https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain

Code:

```
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadOCTable"]')
link.click
```

[image]

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Thanks its worked for NIFTY. But if you select BANKNIFTY (instead of NIFTY), then its not working. Could you please check.

Comment: Could you post the error please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `find_elements_by_xpath` returns you a list, what you would need is `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="downloadOCTable"]")`.

Store the returned object instance in a variable say `element_click`.
Then call click on it as

`element_click.click()`

This should work, or alternatively you can try

```
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadOCTable"]')
link[0].click()
```